# WordPress: Get Post Thumbnail Outside of Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, thumbnails

I am trying to get the post thumbnail image for my carousel thumbnail indicators which are outside of the loop.

Currently it's setup with image placeholders but I need each thumb to represent the currently selected post.

```
 <?php 
    $items = new WP_Query(array(
            'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
            'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'
    ));
    $count = $items->found_posts;
    ?>
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <?php 
            $ctr = 0;
            while ( $items->have_posts() ) :
              $items->the_post();
              $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
              $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
              $link = $custom["more-link"][0];
              $class = $ctr == 0 ? ' active' : '';
            ?>
                  <div class="item<?php echo $class; ?>" id="<? the_ID(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array (
                    'class' => 'img-responsive'
                    )); ?>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a></h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Item -->

                  <?php $ctr++; 
            endwhile;  ?>
                </div>
                <!-- End Carousel Inner -->

                <div class="thumbs">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 active item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    <?php for($num = 1; $num < $count; $num++){ ?>
                    <div class="col-md-2 item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $num; ?>"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- End Carousel -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<?php for($num = 1; $num < $count; $num++){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $num; ?>">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

try using:

```
<?php $counter2 = 0; ?>
<?php while ( $items->have_posts() ) : $items->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $counter2++; ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 item <?php echo $counter2 == 1 ? 'active' : ''; ?>" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $counter2; ?>">
        <a href="#">
            <?php
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array(
                'class' => 'img-responsive'
            ));
            ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This will display it with your markup, but with a thumbnail image instead of the placeholder.

Comment: Thanks! That does work well, however, it removes the red border I have setup on the active item until an item is clicked.

Comment: That didn't fix anything and also caused other issues. When clicking the last of list (the 6th post thumbnail), it removes the main image for that thumbnail... then when clicking other thumbs, screws up the active red border and puts it on other thumbs I'm not clicking.

Comment: Sorry, i'm unable to test the code that i've posted. I've edited it  again - it should be working fine now.

Comment: Better, but still an issue. I have this setup to display only 6 posts despite what the query says. When it first loads, the first post thumb has a red border. It works fine as I click from thumb to thumb, but when I click the last (6th thumb) it starts creating issues. 1) I lose the 6th thumb main image once clicked. 2) After it is clicked, the active thumbs are all messed up.

Comment: This gets out of the question scope. I believe you've resolved your initial issue, and the new issue that you're describing is related with your javascript, and not with the PHP loop code. So i suggest opening a new question for that issue, as it is not directly related with this one.